# Convert very large Blob object (about 3GB) into bytearray in Java

Tags: java, blob

I have read through several websites that showing the sample code to convert `java.sql.Blob` object to `byte[]` and finally saved as a file.

e.g. 
[easiest-way-to-convert-a-blob-into-a-byte-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662432/easiest-way-to-convert-a-blob-into-a-byte-array)
or 
[image-to-bytearray-to-blob-and-blob-to-bytearray-to-image-conversion-issues-in-j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301344/image-to-bytearray-to-blob-and-blob-to-bytearray-to-image-conversion-issues-in-j)

Most of the suggestion use `blob.getBytes(pos, length)`
i.e. 
    `byte[] blobBytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());`

However if the size of the blob more than the maximum value of integer(e.g. 3 GB), the `blobBytes` object will be truncated and the created file will be malformed

Is there anyway to overcome the size limitation of that?

or is it I have to use `blob.getBinaryStream(1, blob.length())` to get InputStream and further process it to byte[]?

Comment: Why would you even want to have 3 GB in memory? So - yes - you should stream the data and work only on portions of the data. And - yes - this is what the `getBinaryStream` method is for.

Comment: Which database do you use ?

Comment: @Berger, I'm using Oracle DB. I checked the blob size can be supported is up to 4GB-1.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, my question arise from a code scan result which highlighted that I downcast a 'long' to 'int' which is used in `blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());`. 
That is a method in my application API which suppose to read a blob from DB and output it as a byte[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Apache IOUtils (which you need to include in your project) and copy the stream to disk.

```
InputStream blobInputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/path/to/file.out"));
IOUtils.copyLarge(blobInputStream, fileOutputStream);
```

- https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

> copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output) Copies bytes from a
>   large (over 2GB) InputStream to an OutputStream.

Edit: You could use blob.getBytes as well, but you would need to pull out a reasonable amount of bytes (e.g. 8192) at a time in a loop, and then write to a FileOutputStream.

Comment: I'll accept this answer as it has directed me to the right answer I want. The maximum size of byte[] can accept is integer. The code will getting exception when exceeding the upper limit, therefore want to convert 3GB blob into byte[] is impossible. The only way to fully process the blob is using InputStream. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a method to get an inputstram, from an `oracle.sql.Blob` :

See :

[Reading and Writing BLOB and CLOB Data](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/oralob.htm#i1058044)

Comment: I suppose the method you suggested is Blob.getBinaryStream(long pos, long length)? Actually I just wanted to find out if InputStream is the only way to handle those kind of big Blob object so that I can make decision on how to modified the API. Thanks